# Unhandled exception at 0x7700C42D in Milestone2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x003EF5DC

Tags: c++

**ErrorState.h**

```
#ifndef ERRORSTATE_ERRORSTATE_H
#define ERRORSTATE_ERRORSTATE_H


#include <iostream>

namespace AMA
{
    class ErrorState
    {
         char* m_message;

    public:
        explicit ErrorState(const char* errorMessage = nullptr);
        //ErrorState(const ErrorState& em) = delete;
        //ErrorState& operator=(const ErrorState& em) = delete;
        void clear();
        bool isClear() const;

        void message(const char* str);

        const char* message()const;
        virtual ~ErrorState();

    };
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, ErrorState&);

}

#endif // !ERRORSTATE_ERRORSTATE_H
```

**ErrorState.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ErrorState.h"

namespace AMA
{

    ErrorState::ErrorState(const char* errorMessage)
    {
        if (errorMessage == nullptr)
        {
            m_message = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            message(errorMessage);
        }
    }
    /*ErrorState::ErrorState(const ErrorState& em) 
    {


    }

    ErrorState& ErrorState::operator=(const ErrorState& em) 
    {
        strncpy(m_message, em.m_message, sizeof(m_message));
        return *this;
    }
    */
    void ErrorState::clear()
    {
        delete [] this->m_message;
        this->m_message = nullptr;
    }

    bool ErrorState::isClear() const
    {
        if (this->m_message == nullptr)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    void ErrorState::message(const char* str)
    {
        //if (isClear() == false)
        //{
        //  clear();
        //}


        this->m_message = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
        strcpy(this->m_message, str);
    }

    const char* ErrorState::message()const
    {
        return this->m_message;
    }
    ErrorState::~ErrorState()
    {
        delete[] this->m_message;
    }

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output,  ErrorState& state)
    {
        if (!state.isClear())
        {
            output << state.message();
        }
        return output;

    }
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ErrorState.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace AMA;

int main() {
    ErrorState T("Testing Error State Module");
    ErrorState e;
    int ret = 0;
    bool ok = true;
    cout << T << endl << e << endl << "isClear(): " << (e.isClear() ? "Passed!" : "Failed!") << endl;
    if (!e.isClear()) ok = false;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "===========| Long Message\r";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        if (i % 1000000 == 0) {
            cout << "*";
            cout.flush();
        }
        e.message("Some error message that is really long long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long");
    }
    cout << '*' << endl;
    cout << e << endl << "isClear(): " << (e.isClear() ? "Failed!" : "Passed!") << endl;
    if (e.isClear()) ok = false;
    cout << endl;

    e.message("Short Message");
    cout << e << endl << e.message() << endl << "isClear(): " << (e.isClear() ? "Failed!" : "Passed!") << endl;
    if (e.isClear()) ok = false;

    e.clear();
    cout << e << endl << "isClear(): " << (e.isClear() ? "Passed!" : "Failed!") << endl;
    if (!e.isClear()) ok = false;
    cout << endl;

    if (ok) {
        cout << "You passed all the tests!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "You did not pass all the tests, keep working on your project!" << endl;
        ret = 1;
    }

    return ret;

}
```

I am trying to create an Error detection kinda program. but in my one of the functions it gives me the error and I don't really know how to fix it as I am new and just learning yet. This is how I need to implement this function that I am not being able to do properly

`void message(const char* str);`

This function stores a copy of the C-style string pointed to by str:

- de-allocates any memory allocated for a previously stored message
- allocates the dynamic memory needed to store a copy of str (remember to include 1 extra byte for the null terminator)
- copies the string at address str to the allocated memory.

Comment: oh ok, sorry about that

Comment: you could use `std::string` and not worry about allocating or deallocating memory manually

Comment: But it's the projects requirement

Comment: Make sure you initialize your members, e.g `ErrorState::ErrorState(const char* errorMessage):  m_message( nullptr)` or inline in the header. `void ErrorState::message(const char* str)
     {
         if (m_message != str)
         {
             if (m_message) // clear
             {
                 delete [] m_message;
                 m_message = nullptr;
             }
             if (str) // Copy
             {
              m_message = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
              strcpy(m_message, str);
             }
         }
     }` and clear in the destructor

Comment: It worked, Thanks so very much.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, we are in the same situation. Just want to help you. I found this on Reddit.  so might help you.

"In your constructor, if you pass in a string then it calls 'message', and the first thing that does is call delete on the [m_message] member. Which hasn't yet been initialized to nullptr. So you are calling delete on a random value, in this case, 0xb754bff4."

```
ErrorMessage::ErrorMessage(const char* errorMessage)
{
m_message = nullptr;

if(errorMessage) 
    message(errorMessage);
}
```